# Android XML : Could not resolve resources

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-resources, android-drawable

So I'm building a game in Android, and I have just created a huge XML file. When I switch to graphical layout in ADT, I'm getting the right layout, so no problems there.

But below the graphical layout, There are two messages:

Couldn't resolve resource @drawable/ic_launcher

Couldn't resolve resource @string/app_name

I have no idea what is causing these problems, as both words ic_launcher and app_name are not found anywhere in my XML.

But I found ic_launcher in all *hdpi folder under res/drawable/ and the string app_name was in res/values/string.xml

Should I have entered XML tags somewhere inside my code? If so, can you please tell me under which tag it should be?

[My XML is composed entirely of nested LinearLayouts and Buttons]

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much! I just refreshed it, and it worrks now!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have errors in other resources (layouts, values, drawables, etc.).

And then clean/refresh/build the project